# Create Future based on result of another Future

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await, flutter

I have a remote async firebase function "checkSubscription" that returns either "true" if the user has a valid subscription or
or "N", where N signifies the number of remaining credits before the user runs out.

To track completion I have these two futures in my class:

```
Future<bool> hasSubscription;
Future<int> remaining;
```

Assume that the datatypes on these cannot be changed.
The remote function is called like this:

```
CloudFunctions.instance
        .call(functionName: 'checkSubscription');
```

This function returns a `Future<dynamic>` with the result.

I'm struggling with the Future logic required to assign my two fields with the required types.
Here is what I came up with

```
Future<void> checkIfUserHasSubscription() async {
    await Future < dynamic > remainingS = CloudFunctions.instance
        .call(functionName: 'isValid');

    if (remaining == "true")
      hasSubscription = true;
    else {
      hasSubscription = false;
      remaining = int.parse(remaining);
    }
  }
```

Obviously this doesn't work because I'm assigning a bool instead of a Future

Any advice?

Comment: Why don’t you use just a `bool` instead?

Comment: Because I have many many places in my code that wait on the result. If the datatype is Future<bool> I can simply: await hasSubscription in each those places, instead of carefully creating callbacks to update each those places once the result comes in.

Comment: Right then. I only asked to understand if you couldn’t be using it in a wrong way. To use with a `Future` see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to have two futures that are completed at a later time. Those futures should be available immediately when you call the check function, but only be completed when you have the result.

For that, you should use a `Completer`.

I'll assume that you only call the check function once. If not, then you should create a new completer on each call, inside the function, and store the futures in mutable fields instead.

```
Future<bool> _hasSubscription;
Future<int> _remaining;
Future<boo> get hasSubscription => 
  _hasSubscription ?? throw StateError("Call checkIfUserHasSubscription first");  
Future<int> get remaining => 
  _remaining ?? throw StateError("Call checkIfUserHasSubscription first");
Future<void> checkIfUserHasSubscription() async {
  // Maybe: if (hasSubscription != null) return;
  var hasSubscriptionCompleter = Completer<bool>();
  var remainingCompleter = Completer<int>();
  _hasSubscription = hasSubscriptionCompleter.future;
  _remaining = remainingCompleter.future;
  var remainings = await
      CloudFunctions.instance.call(functionName: 'isValid');
  if (remaining == "true") {
    hasSubscriptionCompleter.complete(true);
    remainingCompleter.complete(0); // or never complete it.
  } else {
    hasSubscriptionCompleter.complete(false);
    remainingCompleter.complete(int.parse(remaining));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead assign a `Future` with your result:

`hasSubscription = Future<bool>.value(true);`

Comment: Wouldn't this only get executed after the async call is complete though? The idea is to synchronously obtain a Future<bool> and not after CloudFunctions.instance
        .call has already completed(because then I can have the "full" bool).

Comment: This will set the `bool` at this point and all the calls this variable that are awaiting for a value will actually trigger.